# Vanishing product of polynomials over finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

$(x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4)(x_2-x_4-x_3+x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_4-x_2)\equiv 0$ over $\mathbb F_3$.

Take polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_n$ over variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $p_i$ does *not* depend on $x_i$ and $\Pi_{i=1}^n (x_i+p_i) \equiv 0$ over $\mathbb F_q$.
It is easy to see that one can take $n=q$ and $p_i=i+\sum_{j\ne i} x_j$ to satisfy this equation.
If each $p_i$ can depend on only a bounded number of variables, then it follows from the Local Lemma that this is not possible.
It is not that hard to show that for $n=2^{q-1}$ there are polynomials such that each $p_i$ depends on only one $x_j$ with $j<i$; see the example in the first line for $q=3$.

In general, have such polynomials been studied in number theory?

My motivation comes from that this is an equivalent reformulation of the [Hat Guessing Number](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09752) of graphs.
To decide whether such polynimials exists such that their [dependency graph is degenerate](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.04990), would solve an interesting open problem. This graph is defined on $n$ vertices such that $ij\in E$ if $p_i$ depends on $x_j$ or $p_j$ depends on $x_i$. A graph is $d$-degenerate if its vertices can be ordered such that from each vertex $v_i$ there are at most $d$ edges to vertices coming after $v_i$ in this ordering. In our problem $d$ can be any constant, compared to which $q$ and $n$ can be arbitrary.

Comment: by $\equiv 0$ you mean that all values are 0? As a polynomial, this is not identical 0.

Comment: I thought that $x^q-x\equiv 0$ over $\mathbb F_q$. So I mean it like that.

Comment: Ok, I see (I prefer another notation, but it is a matter of taste.) What do you mean by "dependency graph is degenerate"?

Comment: ok and which graph is degenerate?

Comment: I've added the definition to the question, I hope now it's clear.

Comment: I mean, when is a graph called degenerate?

Comment: Sorry, I've added that too.

Comment: does the polynomial in the very first line 'depend' on $x_1$?

Comment: @mathworker21 The point is that the first part in the product is $x_1+p_1$ where $p_1=-x_2-x_3+x_4$, so $p_1$ does not depend on $x_1$.

Comment: @domotorp thanks, but I would still like a definition of 'depend'.

Comment: @mathworker21 A polynomial depends on a variable if changing the value of the variable might change the value of the polynomial. If a polynomial does not depend on a variable, then it can be expressed without the given variable.